# Is there a crossbow in Assassin's Creed?

Tags: assassins-creed

The intro video shows Altair with a crossbow on his back, yet I have not received one after completing the game.  Is it hidden somewhere in the game, or was that just left in the video to tease us?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've noticed, but for completeness' sake: The crossbow is in AC: Brotherhood.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not missing anything :)

The crossbow was replaced during development with the arguably more-versatile throwing knives.

Comment: Lame!  They should have redone the intro movie.  It really got my hopes up!

Comment: I dunno, throwing knives ARE pretty boss...

Comment: Throwing knives are the ultimate! I love seeing them fly with air trails